# Is there a way to identify which process starts an ARP Scan?

Tags: arp

I have 2 machines in my network which regularly scans the whole network `192.168.1.0/24` by sending `"Who has"` packets targetting every ip.

I've googled it, but I didn't find a way to know which process is sending these packets. I know it may be normal but I'd just like to check.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: The system is a `debian` and I have identified the machine sending those arp scans, now I want to identify a process making the system calls responsible for these arp scans, but I don't know how to do that.. ^^
I'd like to know if that's possible to do it blindly, I have an idea which process is responsible if that's easier to do knowing the process (maybe strace on the running process in that case ? I'll try that tomorrow).

Comment: An ARP request should have a MAC address, and an IP address for the requester.  Either of which should let you track it down to the machine level.

Comment: I think this question is far too broad. You haven't told us anything about the systems that you discovered are sending the ARP requests.

Comment: I have already identified the 2 machines Steve, now I want to identify the process.
And sorry it was indeed far too broad, I forgot to mention the machines are running debian.

Comment: This is not a security question, and it does not look like a "network scanner". This looks like normal ARP.

Comment: Ok probably a "not normal" ARP would probably not be periodic and so obvious, making it a regular program doing network discovery. But how is this not network scanning ? (Real question, I genuinely thought it could be labeled this way), and there's still a technical question left to be answered, if that's possible in any way.

Comment: And in another context it could be a security question couldn't it ? Imagine having tcpdump output piped to a script which would log ARP scans (I mean ARP on every IP of the network), this could be the sign of a compromised host, and it would be nice being able to log more info on this scan.